# Sufficient conditions for surface to have at most one point of tangency with sphere

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $S^{n-1}$ be the $n-1$-sphere that lives in $n$ dimensional Euclidean space. Are there simple sufficient conditions for a $(n-1)$ dimensional hypersurface living in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to have at most one point of tangency with $S^{n-1}$? For example hyperplanes obviously satisfy this. In $\mathbb{R}^3$ things like paraboloids satisfy this as well. It seems like there should be some nice intuitive convexity/concavity like description of the hypersurface that would imply such a thing. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Convexity isn't going to help. A paraboloid may be tangent to a sphere along a hypersphere, and the same for ellipsoids.

Answer (score 0):

One sufficient condition is that the distance of the surface to the origin is attained at at most one point.